# Firestore Rule That Checks Single Document Not Authenticating?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm having what I think maybe a simple issue with Firebase Rules, but I can't seem to get this to work.  I have a document 'Companies', with multiple subcollections inside.  I want to set up a rule that checks for admins in an array (with each array item being a string of the firebase userId) inside a 'company' document and allows them to read/write all subcollections of that document.

Here's the data structure in a single company document:

```
company1 {
  admins: ["userid1", "userid2", "userid3"],
}
```

Here's my firebase rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /companies/{company}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(company)).data.admins 
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an example of a query that's not working when it should:

```
let ref = db.collection("companies");

    //get current users company
    ref
      .where("admins", "array-contains", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          this.company = doc.data();
          this.company.id = doc.id;
      });
    });
```

I hope my question makes sense :)

Comment: Please edit the question to show the query that isn't working, along with the relevant data in the database.  We should be able to compare the query and the rule to see if they match as you expect.

Comment: Hey Doug, I added some more information, hopefully that helps with the context!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, I hope it helps anyone who might come upon this.

I ended up adjusting the data structure to include the company document ID as a field in the user doc.  Then, I created these rules to allow users to read/write their own user doc based on firebase authentication, as well as read/write their companies based on a field in the user doc:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Allow users to create and edit the document for themselves in the users collection
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user;
    }

    // Allow users to create a company for themselves upon signup
    match /companies/{company} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null
    }

    match /companies/{company}/{document=**} {
      // Allow users to read/write data on thier own companies
      allow read, write: if company in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.companies
    }
  }
}
```